# Create section in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What's the way to create a section in Facebook, just as Instagram (or AirBnb, Spotify etc.).

I think this was called **Aggregations** or **Collections**: one time I was able to do this, but I can't find the way with the new API…

Thanks

[image: Example of Facebook Section]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

*Alan McConnell, Engineering Manager at Facebook, made the following comment on Open Graph collections in a bug chain on the Facebook Developers site:
“We designed collections to help people express what’s important to them on Timeline. However, after testing with users, we’ve found that few wanted to add custom app collections to their Timeline. Similarly, the traffic to apps who have incorporated custom collections has been limited. As a result, **we are no longer accepting new collection submissions**, although existing custom collections will continue to function.”*

Comment: Giovanni, is that mean that I can't create custom section via Facebook app in personal profile timeline? This is my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532698/how-to-create-facebook-app-that-has-own-custom-section-tab-badge-block-box-in

Comment: No, you can't. No more.

Comment: «although existing custom collections will continue to function»
I also have an app created before 1 Feb 2014 (newgusto), and it still working. For new app, they have special partnership or agreements with FB directly.

Comment: http://marketingland.com/quick-death-facebook-kills-open-graph-collections-developers-72973